# SaaS Platform - Different database user for each user or one master account

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, saas

I have a SaaS platform that I am working on; written in PHP and using a MySQL database (using the PHP PDO class).

The application is already functional and I have decided to use a separate database for each instance.

One of the reasons for using multiple databases is to ensure that client data is separated (and hopefully secure). This also allows us to easily transfer their instance into the on-premise version.

Security is always something that I worry about. I want to ensure this system is as secure as possible before it goes live.

Currently we are using a single MySQL username & password that has access to every database (on that specific MySQL Farm).

Theoretically if there was a security breach then the attacker might be able to access a different database (username & password is unset after the PDO/Database connection is made, but they might be able to run a query such as "use databaseB").

Is this something that I should be concerned about? For example a SaaS platform that simply uses database partitioning is already less secure as a simple SQL error could expose client data.

I've already started looking into using different database usernames & passwords, but it does add to the complexity of the SaaS platform, and keeping things simple is always a good idea.

Thanks!

---

I have decided to go with different usernames and password for each instance.

This is another layer of security and that cannot hurt.

Comment: I don't know how to send a PM on this system.  Are you building proprietary or part of a company/team?

Comment: Hi Phpmeh. Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure what you mean, I am the primary developer on this product (it is being built in-house). Once the system is ready we may get external companies to host it.

Comment: Yes, I was just curious.  I am building business management software that I plan to deploy SaaS style.  I have a junior developer working for me, and we've been working on the project for 6 months.  Even so, it is very slow going.  Always looking to potentially join forces with folks.

Answer (score 1):

> Theoretically if there was a security breach then the attacker might
>   be able to access a different database (username & password is unset
>   after the PDO/Database connection is made, but they might be able to
>   run a query such as "use databaseB").
>
> Is this something that I should be concerned about? For example a SaaS
>   platform that simply uses database partitioning is already less secure
>   as a simple SQL error could expose client data.

1) If you're doing your security right, it should be very difficult (if not impossible) for them to manually write queries.
2) The problem you just laid out is why I would advocate different users/passwords between DBs.
3) Another reason I would encourage multiple DB connects... I made manufacturing control software for a company that had approximately 10 people in operations.  It did not take very long for the database to become huge.  Multiple databases will keep the size in control better than 1.
4) I would be much more concerned about a client accidently accessing another company's information via a problem as simple as permission problems if I was using only 1 database.

The question I still have lingering concerning partitioning the databases (I haven't researched/tested yet)... I have a good understanding of how to handle hundred of connections to 1 database.  What happens when you handle just a few connections to a hundred databases instead?

Comment: 1) Yes of course, all queries go via Bound Parameters with the PHP PDO class.
2) Yes that is my main question, if this extra step of security should be used.
3) Yes we will be using multiple databases.
4) Agreed, this is another reason why we are using multiple DBs.

I don't believe connections should cause a huge issue, although the extra connections will probably take up some more memory.